# Executing function from another file in the current scope

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function in file `commands.js`, roughly it looks like this:

```
class DirectMessageCommand {
    constructor(name, instructions){
        this.name = name
        this.instructions = instructions
    }
}

const commands = [
   new DirectMessageCommand('name_1', () => {...}),
   new DirectMessageCommand('name_2', () => {...}),
   new DirectMessageCommand('name_3', () => {...}),
   new DirectMessageCommand('name_4', () => {...})
]

exports.DirectMessageCommand = DirectMessageCommand
exports.commands = commands
```

I then want to call those functions in `main.js` by first, importing:

```
const { DirectMessageCommand, commands } = require('./commands.js')
```

And secondly, once I get command input, by iterating list of command objects, call needed function:

```
const command_line = message.split(' ')
for(let i = 0; i < commands.length; i++){
    if(command_line[0] == commands[i].name){
        commands[i].instructions.call(this)
    }
}
```

But since in commands list in `commands.js` in instructoins functions of `DirectMessageCommand` objects I refer to variables from `main.js` as I'm plannig to use commands list only in `main.js`, I get a error:
`ReferenceError: var_a is not defined`, where `var_a` is a variable defined in `main.js` and is being used in `DirectMessageCommand` instruction functions before any instruction fucntions have been called from imported commands list.

So my question is: how do I call functions defined in `commands.js` in a scope of `main.js`?

Comment: Look up how to export symbols from a CommonJS module

Comment: @MemeComposer if I understand you correctly, I'm doing a proper export from JS module. If not, could you point me exactly, what I'm doing wrong, I'll be very grateful

Answer (score 1):

If `var_a` is definede like `const/let/var` in *main.js* this variable doesn't passed to istructions function using `.call(this)`, you can call the function passing variable directly in the arguments like `commands[i].instructions(var_a)` or, but I'm not pretty sure, add to arguments of `call()` the `var_a` like that `commands[i].instructions.call(this, var_a)`.

In *commands.js* declare your object like that `.... new DirectMessageCommand('name_1', (var_a) => {....}), .....` so, in your function you can use `var_a`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I was thinking about this way of solving my problem, but the things is, I gave one variable var_a just for example, but trully I have 3 or more variables in main.js scope, some og which are quite huge, so passing those big variables back and forth is a perfomance concerns

Comment: ok, can you post the structure of main.js and an example of instruction function?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems to check in your live code:

1. You're missing semicolons on nearly every line, which is going to cause unexpected behavior.  That is most likely the cause of the var_a error.
2. In your example there's no reason to pass the scope to the DirectMessageCommand so you could do without .call(this).

[Here's a working version of your code.](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-benz-lur2s?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

commands.js

```
class DirectMessageCommand {
  constructor(name, instructions) {
    this.name = name;
    this.instructions = instructions;
  }
}

const commands = [
  new DirectMessageCommand("name_1", () => {
    document.getElementById("app").innerHTML += "name_1 called<br />";
  }),
  new DirectMessageCommand("name_2", () => {
    document.getElementById("app").innerHTML += "name_2 called<br />";
  }),
  new DirectMessageCommand("name_3", () => {
    document.getElementById("app").innerHTML += "name_3 called<br />";
  }),
  new DirectMessageCommand("name_4", () => {
    document.getElementById("app").innerHTML += "name_4 called<br />";
  })
];

exports.DirectMessageCommand = DirectMessageCommand;
exports.commands = commands;
```

main.js

```
const { DirectMessageCommand, commands } = require("./commands.js");

const message = "name_1 name_2 name_4 name_3";

const command_line = message.split(" ");

for (let a = 0; a < command_line.length; a++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
    if (command_line[a] === commands[i].name) {
      commands[i].instructions.call(this);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Regarding your first point, I'm new to JS, so I've read 2 articles on this topic, both of which suggested that usage of semicolons in NodeJS is not a necessety. As for using .call(this), I tried this before and it doesn't work, it gives me the same error.

Comment: Newer flavors of JS are more tolerant of fewer semicolons but you're writing in ES5 and they're required.  But it's best practices to always use semicolons no matter the flavor.  Regarding .call(this) your issue is most likely related to the lack of semicolons but reference my working example to help you out.